# How to collect table Column in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, local-storage

I have dynamically to move entire columns left or right in table

I want to set column position in local storage when close browser and open again

**example** : I have column [1 2 3] and I move column 3 to left [3 1 2] when close browser and open again

table column is [3 1 2] because local storage get Item form table column

Does anyone know a way to save entire column position in local storage ?

This my all code Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yLzw150d/

```html
<table class="table" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Sorry for my bad English, can't explain all what I need, hope you understand what I need

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save `table` **innerHTML** to localStorage.

```
var tableContent = document.getElementById('table').innerHTML;
localStorage.setItem('tableContent', tableContent);
```

And then get the value and set it back to HTML.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("tableContent") !== null) {
    var tableContent = localStorage.getItem('tableContent');
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = tableContent;
}
```

Check [this](https://codepen.io/navenoc13/pen/vYmzOrv) out.
You can try to drag and then refresh, it will maintain previous column position.

Comment: Ah yes that work !! but you can explain why need check `tableContent !== null`  ? Thanks!!

Comment: Because the first time you load your page, localStorage is still empty, so `tableContent` is still a null variable, or in other words, it's **undefined**.